# Delete calendar event in google calendar ics file

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am creating calendar event ics file with **PUBLISH** method and sending that attachment in the email. When receiving in email there is option  for adding event to **Add to calendar** which will add event in the calendar.
For deleting calendar event i am sending delete calendar as an attachment in the email.

Code for **creating calendar event**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID://Company//Company Calendar 1.0//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:lAdYuWyFqwyopPjAAA123
DTSTAMP:2020-02-03T05:04:52.793ZZ
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Calcutta:20200204T100000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Calcutta:20200204T100000
SUMMARY:Play cricket
DESCRIPTION:Description of the event
SEQUENCE:0
CATEGORIES:Sports
ORGANIZER;CN=Admin:mailto:abc@test.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Code for **deleting calendar event**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID://Company//Company Calendar 1.0//EN
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:lAdYuWyFqwyopPjAAA123
DTSTAMP:2020-02-03T05:04:52.793ZZ
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Calcutta:20200204T100000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Calcutta:20200204T100000
SUMMARY:Play cricket
DESCRIPTION:Description of the event
CATEGORIES:Sports
ORGANIZER;CN=Admin:mailto:abc@test.com
STATUS:CANCELLED
SEQUENCE:1
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

It is working when email is send in the outlook it is automatically cancelling the event when deleting event ics file is received in the email. It is striking the event in outlook calendar.

But when i am checking with gmail it is not removing event when delete event is received. After delete event is received in the email google calendar shows same event over there.

I only want to use **PUBLISH** method while creating event. **Don't** want use **REQUEST** method while creating event using ics file as it will create unnecessary **RVSP** option.

I have tried to keep sequence same that also didn't work. Even it tried adding **X-WR-RELCALID** this parameter even this was also not working.

Comment: If you want to delete a Google Calendar event, use the [Google Calendar API method](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete)

Comment: @ ziganotschka I don't want to use third party tool.Is there any way to that natively through ics file in gmail / google calendar, using native ics file it is working fine in outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Try with METHOD:PUBLISH but a STATUS:CANCELLED